# ConTeXt and Sublime Text 3

Tags: context

Where can I find information to set up ConTeXt on Sublime Text 3. I really like this editor and I have used it to create my documents in Latex/Latextools. But now, I am learning about ConTeXt and I would love to use my favorite editor.

Comment: There are no highlighting patterns available for ConTeXt in Sublime Text 3.  [Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Category:Text_Editors) lists some ConTeXt enabled editors if you'd like to switch.  Otherwise you would have to [write the highlighting patterns](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) on your own.

Comment: BTW, the “official” ConTeXt editor is [SciTE](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/scite-context-readme.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

There is now a Sublime Text 3 package for ConTeXt, called [Simple ConTeXt](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/simple_ConTeXt).  Maybe it will do what you want: it includes syntax highlighting, a build system, and some auto-completion stuff.

Disclaimer: I am it's author.  I felt the same as you, that I like Sublime as a text editor, and desired some quality of life things when writing ConTeXt documents with it.  So I tried to remedy the situation myself, as best as I could.  Any feedback or issues/pull requests etc. are welcome, though I can't guarantee I'll have the time to look at them.

Comment: Thanks for the package! Added Sublime to [this wiki page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Text_Editors).